# Look up and return values from 2 columns all matches

Tags: excel, lookup

I have List A and B in excel and would like to compare ALL the items in List A with ALL the records in List B and if they match or partial match return the value of B in 3rd column.  Hopefully demonstrated in the attached.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj1kl.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it is to use VBA. Please find below example function which you can use in the same way as Excel functions:

```
Public Function findArea(item As String, areaRng As Range) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ARR_area() As Variant

ARR_area = areaRng.Value2

For i = LBound(ARR_area) To UBound(ARR_area)
    If (item Like "*" & ARR_area(i, 1) & "*") Then
        findArea = ARR_area(i, 1)
        GoTo endFunc
    End If
Next i

endFunc:

End Function
```

Where:
item - Item which you want to check vs. areas
area - range of areas you want to check.

See usage example:
[image]

To achieve this result without you would need to format table to pivot view, where in rows you would have item and in rows area - as the value you can check matching for each combination. Nevertheless in this particular example I would recommend to use VBA.

Hope it helped.